# Can not append all content to my portfolio

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm working on my portfolio and one section is to show "cards" to my projects. Next, I started working on the ability to sort the cards depending on what kind of project it is.

So if I click "Web Development" it will only display the cards with projects related to that.

I have an object with all the data for the cards and one key is `"tag"` with the value that relates to the project, for example: `"Web Development"`.

I can then run an "if" statement to only show "Web Development" for example.

After that, I empty the element (`<div>`) which contains the cards and then append the cards that only have the correct tag with jQuery `empty().append()`

It works but it only appends one card. If I have more project cards in that tag it won't append unless I'm doing a `setTimeout` but then the other divs and such move and makes the portfolio "glitchy" for a while.

Any suggestions?

```js
const projects = {
    cards: {
      card1: {
        name: "",
        skills: "",
        thumbnail: "",
        github: "",
        live: "",
        tag: "webdevelopment",
        underConstruction: "no"
      },
      card2: {
        name: "",
        skills: "",
        thumbnail: "",
        github: "",
        live: "",
        tag: "webdevelopment",
        underConstruction: "no"
      },
      card3: {
        name: "",
        skills: "",
        thumbnail: "",
        github: "",
        live: "",
        tag: "devOps",
        underConstruction: "no"
      },

    },
    sortCards: () => {
      let cards = Object.values(projects.cards);

      for (let sort of cards) {

        let tagSort = sort.tag.toLowerCase();

        $('.devops').click(function() {
          if (tagSort == "devops") {
            $('.project-container').empty().append(`
                    <div class="card" data-skills="${sort.skills}"> 
                        <div class="card-thumbnail">
                            <img src="${sort.thumbnail}" alt="${sort.name}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-link">
                        <a href="${sort.live}" target="_rel"><img src="iamtt/../assets/images/live.png" alt"Live"></a>
                        <a href="${sort.github}" target="_rel"><img src="iamtt/../assets/images/github-live.png" alt="github"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `)
          }
        })

        $('.webdevelopment').click(function() {
          if (tagSort == "webdevelopment") {
            $('.project-container').empty().append(`
                    <div class="card" data-skills="${sort.skills}"> 
                        <div class="card-thumbnail">
                            <img src="${sort.thumbnail}" alt="${sort.name}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-link">
                        <a href="${sort.live}" target="_rel"><img src="iamtt/../assets/images/live.png" alt"Live"></a>
                        <a href="${sort.github}" target="_rel"><img src="iamtt/../assets/images/github-live.png" alt="github"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `)
          }
        })
      }
    },
    // ...
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="webdevelopment">#WebDevelopment</div>
<div class="devops">#DevOps</div>

<!-- Projects and skills-->
<div id="projectskill">
  <div class="space-top"></div>
  <div class="projectskill-content">
    <!-- projects cards -->
    <div class="project-container"></div>
    <!-- skills-->
    <div class="skills-container">
      <div class="skills">
        <div class="skills-text">
          <span class="my-skills">MY SKILLS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="icons"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can simplify the code by adding an attribute like `data-tag` to the
  tag elements.
- When a tag is clicked, get the value of the `data-tag`
  attribute and find it's related cards from `projects.cards`.

Try this

```js
const projects = {
  cards: {
    card1: {
      name: "",
      skills: "",
      thumbnail: "",
      github: "",
      live: "",
      tag: "webdevelopment",
      underConstruction: "no"
    },
    card2: {
      name: "",
      skills: "",
      thumbnail: "",
      github: "",
      live: "",
      tag: "webdevelopment",
      underConstruction: "no"
    },
    card3: {
      name: "",
      skills: "",
      thumbnail: "",
      github: "",
      live: "",
      tag: "devOps",
      underConstruction: "no"
    },

  },
  sortCards: () => {
    let cards = Object.values(projects.cards);
    let container = $('.project-container');

    // add sort links
    let tags = [...new Set(cards.map(sort => sort.tag))];
    $('.sort-links').html(tags.map(tag => `<div class="devops" data-tag="${tag}">#${tag}</div>`).join(''));

    // sort tags
    $('.sort-links').on('click', '[data-tag]', function() {
      let tag = $(this).data('tag');
      let tagCards = cards.filter(o => o.tag === tag).map(sort => (`
                <div class="card" data-skills="${sort.skills}"> 
                    <div class="card-thumbnail">
                        <img src="${sort.thumbnail}" alt="${sort.name}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-link">
                    <a href="${sort.live}" target="_rel"><img src="iamtt/../assets/images/live.png" alt"Live"></a>
                    <a href="${sort.github}" target="_rel"><img src="iamtt/../assets/images/github-live.png" alt="github"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `));

      container.html(tagCards.join(''));
    })
  }
}

// test
projects.sortCards();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sort-links"></div>

<!-- Projects and skills-->
<div id="projectskill">
  <div class="space-top"></div>
  <div class="projectskill-content">
    <!-- projects cards -->
    <div class="project-container"></div>
    <!-- skills-->
    <div class="skills-container">
      <div class="skills">
        <div class="skills-text">
          <span class="my-skills">MY SKILLS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="icons"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```